# SVN Update to a revision in revision history got through merge

Tags: svn, merge

I have two branches maintained in an SVN repository. Developers commit changes to one branch and an automated process merges the changes to second branch. I can see all the revision history in second branch. Now I have a working copy pointing to second branch. Here I can see all the revisions; but I could not update to a revision propagated through merge. Is there anyways to perform a merge to get revisions in both the branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update WC to revision, which change content below WC-root. In your case, if WC-root is branch2-root, you can

- Switch your WC to branch1 and back to branch2
- Switch to parent folder for both branches (`/branches`) of checkout new WC from /branches (which will have all existing branches under `/branches` in it)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question, so please bear with me.

It seems you want to update to a specific revision of `branch 1` which corresponds to a specific revision of `branch 2`.

One way to do it is to tag `branch 1` right before you merge it into `branch 2`.